# Every element in the subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ generated by $X$ can be obtained from elements of $X$ by a finite sequence of field operations.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I wish to show that the subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ generated by $X$, call it $K$, is the same as the set-call it $S$-of all elements of $\mathbb{C}$ that can be obtained from elements of $X$ by a finite sequence of field operations, where $X\neq{0}$ or $\emptyset$.

$S\subset K$ is easy; but I failed to show that $K\subset S$. Any hint would be appreciated.

(PS, I have little to no foundation in field theory.)

Comment: Hint: $K$ is the intersection of all subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ containing $X$.

Comment: @Jose27 I appreciate the hint-that indeed is the definition of $K$. Still, I failed to make any meaning progress.

Comment: Can you prove that for a field $X\subset L\subset \mathbb{C}$ we must have $S\subset L$?

Comment: Your definition of $K$ is the intersection of all subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ containing $X$. It's clear that $S$ contains $X$, so it is enough to show that $S$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$, since then it is evident that $S$ must contain $K$. Can you see why $S$ is a subfield?

Comment: @AlexWertheim That worked! Thank you so much! (we were never introduced to field, only to subfield, which is my lame excuse).

Comment: @DickGrayson: no excuses necessary - I'm glad it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S$ is a subfield of $\Bbb C$. Indeed if $a$ and $b$ are complex numbers that can be obtained by a finite number of field operations $+,-,*,/$ from numbers in $X$, then so are $a+b, a-b, a*b$ and, if $b\ne 0$, then $a/b$. Since $K$ is the intersection of all subfields containing $X$, $K\subseteq  S$.